# CSS Material Icons

Tags: css, material-ui

We have CSS classes that render icons. 
The CSS class is used all over different pages.

```
.alert { /* used for "alert" type messages */
background: url(images/alerts.png) no-repeat left top;
padding: 5px 0 15px 35px;
margin: 0;
}
Use:
<p id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMessageParagraph" style="clear:both" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" 
aria-atomic="true" class="alert">Thank you for using the site&nbsp;</p>
```

We need to replace all these icons with material-icons.
Can this be done in stylesheet or it will require going through all pages and adding for example `<i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>` ?

Comment: Can this be done in stylesheet or it will require going through all pages and adding for example 
      <i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

Declare Material Icons stylesheet in your header.

Replace your alert class using a pseudo-element.

Adapt the following CSS.

`.alert::after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: 'error_outline';
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}`